# why does Earth have three wind cells instead of just one?

Tags: wind, geothermal-heat, equator

I wondered what causes three wind cells on earth -Hadley Cells, Ferrel Cells, and Polar Cells, instead of just a one big cell from equator to the pole?

I'd like a straightforward, intuitive explanation as to why there are multiple cells. The actual calculations aren't as important.

Comment: Is it possible to give a more intuitive, descriptive, less-mathmatic shorter answer here than that possible duplicate account @Spencer proposed?

Comment: Any new requirements of your question should be edited into the body. I've done that for you; let's see if it prevents the question from being closed.

Comment: It's a complicated subject to model and keep in mind, models aren't perfect.   Doing a little google searching on this, this article comes closest to an intuitive explanation but it's still got some math.  https://www.seas.harvard.edu/climate/eli/research/equable/hadley.html   Earth's rate of rotation and the height of the troposphere, heat from the sun, placement of the continents, abundant water vapor and temperature variation may all factors to varying degrees.   Not everything is easy to explain intuitively, but I invite someone to give it a try.